# C++: No matching function to call to const char

Tags: c++, method-parameters

im trying to create a object called player in class player.

```
#include <string>
#ifndef PLAYER_HH
#define PLAYER_HH

using namespace std;

class Player
{
public:
    Player(string name, int points);
    const string get_name();
    int get_points();
    void add_points(int pts);
    bool has_won();
private:
    string _name;
};

#endif // PLAYER_HH
```

from player.cpp:

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

Player::Player(string name):
    _name(name), _points(0){
}
```

Now, the problem is, in the main function i get this error:

```
 error: no matching function for call to ‘Player::Player(const char [6])’
 Player player1 = Player("Matti");
                                ^
```

Shouldn't the compiler be able to convert it to a string?

edit: Here is the full main.cpp that i'm not supposed to be changing:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "player.hh"


int main()
{
    Player player1 = Player("Matti");
    Player player2 = Player("Teppo");
    Player* in_turn = 0;

    int turn = 1;
    while (true)
    {
        if (turn % 2 != 0)
        {
            in_turn = &player1;
        }
        else
        {
            in_turn = &player2;
        }

        std::cout << "Enter the score of player " << in_turn->get_name()
             << " of turn " << turn << ": ";
        int pts = 0;
        std::cin >> pts;

        in_turn->add_points(pts);
        if (in_turn->has_won())
        {
            std::cout << "Game over! The winner is " << in_turn->get_name() << "!" << std::endl;
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Scoreboard after turn " << turn << ":" << std::endl;
        std::cout << player1.get_name() << ": " << player1.get_points() << "p" << std::endl;
        std::cout << player2.get_name() << ": " << player2.get_points() << "p" << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;

        turn += 1;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

You guys are awesome with your fast answers :-)

Comment: "_Shouldn't the compiler be able to convert it to a string?_" Yes, it very well can convert it to a `std::string`. That is not the problem though: There is no constructor declared that accepts **only** a `std::string`, there's an additional `int` argument that you forgot to pass to a constructor.

Comment: your declaration has `Player(string,int)` but the definition is for `Player(string)`

Comment: This is an assignment, and i'm not supposed to change the main.cpp. Both players have a specific amount of points. Is there a way to assign int points to both players without them being declared in the first place?

Comment: See my answer, use a default value for the score parameter.

Comment: If you're not supposed to change main.cpp, you're also not supposed to change the constructor's prototype or remove the `_points` member, and both players start with zero points.

Comment: i am a bit confused, because also answers refer to your main.cpp, but you dont show it in the question, do you?

Comment: Thanks you for everybody's help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declared the constructor of player as `Player(string name, int points);`.

If you define a function with two parameters you have to use both.

Create your object with

```
Player player1 = Player("Matti", 0);
```

If you still want to call it with just one parameter you have to set a default value like this.

```
class Player
{
public:
    ...
    Player(string name, int points = 0); // replace 0 with whatever you want to be default.
    ...
}
```

Then you can use both variants. The one above and the one you attempted

```
Player player1 = Player("Matti");
```

Of course the function header of your definition has to match the one in the declaration:

```
Player::Player(string name, int points):
    _name(name), _points(points){
}
```

It's important not to write the default value inside dhe definition because this will most likely produce an compiler error.

Comment: This would still result in linker errors ;) The function definition also needs to be changed

Comment: @xEric_xD - I tried this with GNU compiler and i don't have to adapt the definition. I even get an error if i try to add a default value to it.

Comment: It's not about the default value. The declared constructor `Player(string name, int points);` does not have a definition in the code provided by OP. He only defines `Player::Player(string name)`, which in turn doesn't have a declaration

Answer (score 2):

The conversion from `const char[6]` to `std::string` will work and is not the issue here.

Your constructor has **two** parameters, you cannot simply omit the second one. If you like to create `Player` objects with a default score, declare your constructor as:

```
Player(string name, int points = 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you declare your constructor having two parameters:

```
Player(string name, int points);
```

but define it as having only one:

```
Player::Player(string name):
    _name(name), _points(0){
}
```

That should give you compilation error.  Either remove the second param from the declaration in class body and keep main.cpp as it is or add second param to the definition in `player.cpp`:

```
Player::Player(string name, int points):
    _name(name), _points(points){
}
```

and then specify value for 'points' explicitly:

```
Player("Matti", 0);
```

You can also have both - just add default value for `points`:

```
class Player
{
...
   Player(string name, int points = 0);
};
```

Then, both of these lines will work:

```
Player player1 ("Matti");
Player player2 ("Matti", 0);
```